# How to receive an measurement via RaspberryPi GPIO

Tags: python, pi-zero

Existing codebase being written in python, now requires attaching a new device.

Purpose of that device will be to measure analog angle, convert to some format of a number and send it to rpi via some pins. At this stage, there is a good deal of a freedom what pins to use, so lets consider the fresh state where all pins are unused.

Analog-to-digital converter will be made by a contractor, I need to prepare a specific technical specification - the task in what format I want that angle measurement to be sent to the rpi.

What is the best practice to send and receive such measurements with RaspberryPi + Python?

Maybe some sort of a square wave with certain time distance between signals generated by measurement device and a loop in python that counts those waves? I am sure there gotta be a existing way to do such a stuff, with all the error correction and other stuff.

PS: I have experience reading simple digital on/off states, but not with something more complex.

Comment: Just wire up an MCP3008 or similar https://learn.adafruit.com/mcp3008-spi-adc/python-circuitpython

Comment: If you need a commercial spec for your contractor, several people here are available for fee. This is a bit broad in scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi supports multiple different [serial communication protocols](https://www.mbtechworks.com/hardware/raspberry-pi-UART-SPI-I2C.html): I2C, SPI, and UART.

I'd suggest you ask the contractor to build the ADC to comply with one of these protocols. I believe then you only need to agree on the format of the data. One common way to format sensor data is using a `.json` file. Here is an [example](https://github.com/porrey/i2c) that I found in a Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908949/sending-a-json-string-via-i2c-between-arduino-and-rpi-iot-c-sharp?rq=1).

Comment: What do you mean by JSON? Isn't it too complex to make an ADC to generate JSON?

Comment: @Deele, some sensors that send data to a system such as a Raspberry Pi or Arduino as a json file. You can use a Python library to read the data. However, if this is not suitable for your application maybe try to check other ways to format the data. At its most basic, you might only need to transmit the data in bit form. Then, depending on how robust you require your application to be, you may add an [error correction code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction).

Comment: I was just asking because I don't know what is a good practice. I imagine that generating a string of characters is much complicated for a simple ADC, than send, for example, an integer. It will be bad If I ask the contractor to create something that I can't handle. :)

Comment: @Deele, I agree, but it really depends on what microcontroller unit you use for the ADC. For simple projects I've built devices that just send over integers, and that's been good enough. Will your ADC be connected via cable to the RPi, or is anything going to be sent wirelessly? Because if it's all by wire, I wouldn't worry myself with error correction codes. Furthermore, the advantage I see with json files is that you can neatly send multiple data, but, if you're only concerned about the value of the angle, then you could also omit using json.

Comment: You need to check the specifications for the ADC that will be used.  I've never personally encountered an ADC that does anything but provide a binary number over some communications protocol, e.g. SPI or I2C.  But if you're writing a specification for a contract, you cannot do this in abstract, it must be done in context of the hardware, which should also be in the specification.

Answer (score 1):

How many bits accuracy do you need in the ADC conversion?  Typical off the shelf ADCs may have 8, 10, 12, 14, or 16 bits of resolution.

One of those will probably be perfect for your application.

Choose an ADC with the appropriate resolution and an appropriate interface supported by the Pi (e.g. I2C or SPI).

Then do a search for that ADC and Raspberry Pi to see if there are many tutorials.  If there are it will be a safe choice.  The ADC itself will define the data format.